# How to fetch the photo captured time in android

Tags: android

I need to attach picture from gallery and also get the captured time of the picture selected.  Is it possible to get the time?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link [here](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/reading-exif-information-from-a-picture-file-in-android) .There will get all what you need

And here is the required code,

```
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePhoto.getPath());
    String date=exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the picture is .png because png-files doesn't have exif data.

Comment: @vilpe89: he actually need the captured time.And the captured image most probably  will be jpeg not png...

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This code will open the gallery and when you select a picture it will get the real path and the date, then you can do what ever you like with those.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (bitmap != null) bitmap.recycle();

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);

        File selectedFile = new File(realPath);
        Date date = new Date(selectedFile.lastModified());
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date);

        Log.i("File path", realPath);
        Log.i("File time", time);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(realPath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only gives me the date but no time.

Comment: You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Like this: String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date);

Comment: I edited the code for you, it now includes the time variable what you wanted to!

Answer (score 1):

After you select any image from gallery you will get a result in `onActivityResult`, use the below code in the `onActivityResult`

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

Where `data` is the `Intent` in `onActivityResult`

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null,
                null, null);
cursor .moveToFirst();
int column_index_date_taken = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
int column_index_date_added = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);

String dateTaken = cursor.getString(column_index_date_taken);
String dateAdded = cursor.getString(column_index_date_added);
```